# How do I mark a unit test as skipped in Netbeans test results window? (C++)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans, ide

**tl;dr:** I am writing a C++ project using netbeans and am looking for a way to mark a unit test as skipped.

Details:

I am using Netbeans IDE for C++ development. When adding a unit test (steps [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html#addsimple)), the IDE generates C++ code with output looking like this:

```
%SUITE_STARTING%
%SUITE_STARTED%
%TEST_STARTED% time=0 testname (suitename)
%TEST_FAILED%
%TEST_FINISHED%
%SUITE_FINISHED%
```

This is an output format that Netbeans parses nicely and displays in a test results window.

I have updated my test code with a unit test class and a test suite class that generate this output dynamically, and it works.

My problem is that I would like to mark a unit test as "skipped" (as in, not succeeded, not failed, not executed at all). There are various reasons for this (specifying tests before implementing them, skipping a test because it is blocked by a known defect, etc).

**Question: Is this supported by the IDE (the test results window has a "show skipped tests" button but with no effect as far as I can see), and what kind of output token should the code generate for a test to be "skipped"? (I have tried `%TEST_SKIPPED%` and `%TEST_SKIPPED% testname` but the test results window simply ignores the line.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Not supported by the IDE out of the box, in order to get this working you would need to patch the IDE at the very least.

**Details :**

Netbeans does support skipped tests as per [here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/dfd26cdc982a/gsf.testrunner/src/org/netbeans/modules/gsf/testrunner/api/Status.java).

However the logic for updating the UI from parsing the output of the test runner as per [here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/e3a9ee45ad56/cnd.testrunner/src/org/netbeans/modules/cnd/testrunner/ui/CndUnitHandlerFactory.java) doesn't support skipped tests regardless of whether the built in Simple Test or CUnit Test is used.

In order to get something skipped test support working you would need to generate the relevant SkippedTestHandler as part of [CndUnitHandlerFactory.java](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/e3a9ee45ad56/cnd.testrunner/src/org/netbeans/modules/cnd/testrunner/ui/CndUnitHandlerFactory.java), along with any other modifications to CodeGeneration which is done as part of the [Simple Unit Test](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/e3a9ee45ad56/cnd.simpleunit/src/org/netbeans/modules/cnd/simpleunit/codegeneration/CodeGenerator.java) built in or any unit test framework which you add support by creating a custom module for following the instructions [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CND69UnitTestsPluginTutotial).

Also if you wanted to use CUnit you would have also give it support for skipped tests with a patch similar to [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cunit/patches/22/)